# how lb check master health in a OpenShift HA cluster

Tags: openshift

How does LB check master health? Does LB only check master API health, or it also implicitly checks etcd health?

Suppose I have an OpenShift HA cluster with 3 masters and etcd collocates with masters. Assume split-brain happened, the cluster split into two parts. At the minority part, etcd loses quorum and cannot serve requests from API server. Are this master being marked healthy by LB?